# Apache commonsのライブラリを使ってFTPサーバーにアップロードしたいができない

Tags: android, java

AndroidでApache commons netを使用してFTPサーバーにテキストファイルをアップロードするプログラムを作りたいのですがReply Code 500が返されてできません。
以下がそのプログラムです(実際はAsyncTaskの中に入っています)。

```
    private class FTP extends ContextWrapper{

    public FTP(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    private String putData{
        int reply = 0;
        boolean isLogin = false;
        FTPClient FTPCl = new FTPClient();

        try {
            FTPCl.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            FTPCl.connect("*****.*****.jp",21);
            reply = FTPCl.getReplyCode();
            if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
                throw new Exception("Connect Status:" + String.valueOf(reply));
            }

            if (!FTPCl.login(<ユーザーID>, <パスワード>)) {
                throw new Exception("Invalid user/password");
            }
            isLogin = true;

            FTPCl.enterLocalActiveMode();

            FTPCl.setDataTimeout(15000);
            FTPCl.setSoTimeout(15000);
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = this.openFileInput("hoge.txt");

            FTPCl.storeFile("files/", fileInputStream);
            reply = FTPCl.getReplyCode();
            if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
                throw new Exception("Send Status:" + String.valueOf(reply));
            }
            fileInputStream.close();


            FTPCl.logout();
            isLogin = false;

            FTPCl.disconnect();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        } finally {
            if (isLogin) {
                try {
                    FTPCl.logout();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
            }
            if (FTPCl.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    FTPCl.disconnect();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
            }
            FTPCl = null;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: 500が返されるのは `FTPCl.storeFile()` の後でしょうか？

Comment: FTPCl.storeFileの後です

Answer (score 1):

ドキュメントによると、
`FTPCl.storeFile`の第一引数はディレクトリではなくファイル名のようです。
[storeFile(java.lang.String, java.io.InputStream)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#storeFile(java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream))

Workingディレクトリを変更するメソッドが用意されています。
[changeWorkingDirectory(java.lang.String)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#changeWorkingDirectory(java.lang.String))

[こちらの回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1651337/5183999)が参考になるかもしれません。